# Resizing Views before drawing

Tags: java, android, android-view

In my layout I have a GridView containing 4 custom ImageViews. I'm setting GridView's visibility to invisible until all ImageViews are resized at first but when the GridView is shown, there's a short blink with ImageViews still unchanged.

[blink for a split second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l59Ok.png)

[views are resized in a moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sq2Y.png)

Each ImageView creates separate listener in order to scale its size:

```
//Setting new params as half of parent's size and increasing counter  

if (getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

            View parent = (View) getParent();
            int dimension = Math.min(parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight()) / 2;
            mThisImageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(dimension, dimension));
            ResizeCounter.setCounter(ResizeCounter.getCounter() + 1);

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

```
//Activity listens to the moment when all ImageViews have been resized  

ResizeCounter.addCounterListener(new OnResizeCounterChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResizeCounterChanged() {
        if (ResizeCounter.getCounter() == 4) {
            mAnswerGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

I've also tried to resize them in onGlobalLayout method (same result) and to override onMeasure method (parent View is still null at this point).
I suspect that it's too late to change views in onPreDraw() but is there a method that can be called earlier inside which I can be sure that all views have been measured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `mAnswerGridView.requestLayout()` before `mAnswerGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

This may not work because as it's stated at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout())

> This will **schedule** a layout pass of the view tree.

So you may better force relayout:

```
relayoutChildren(View view) {
view.measure(
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getMeasuredWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
view.layout(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom()); }
```

Comment: I've tried requestLayout and invalidate methods but with no effect.

Comment: Yay, using given method did the job although I don't quite understand why. Shouldn't requestLayout() call these two methods (measure and layout) as well?

Comment: Yes it should, but it doesn't call that methods immediately

Comment: Thank you! How about if I do not want to force relayout,
do you know such a mechanism to hold setting visibility until the scheduled method is finished?

Comment: Yep, setting a Handler will also work, because it will be added to the end of MessageQueue and so run after all scheduled calculations are made

Answer (score 1):

I've created a handler that schedules setting visibility right after calling requestLayout.
Works well in this case.

```
ResizeCounter.addCounterListener(new OnResizeCounterChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResizeCounterChanged() {
        if (ResizeCounter.getCounter() == 4) {
            mAnswerGridView.requestLayout();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAnswerGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```